# How to tell cpan (ActiveState) to use MinGW compiler

Tags: perl, compilation, mingw, cpan

I used to use MinGW for compiling cpan modules. Now on my new computer i installed VisualStudio and CPAN now tries to to use the vs-compiler and fails because it can't find "sys/types.h".

How do I tell cpan to use MinGW? I couldn't find a commoand-line option for this. Can i fix the problem otherise using vs-compiler? Where would I put sys/types.h? How do I pass the include command from cpan to the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to compile CPAN modules with a different C compiler than your Perl was built with, you're asking for trouble. The typical Perl module with XS code uses the compiler flags from your Perl config (see `perl -V`). Since ActivePerl is built with MSVC, `$Config{ccflags}` contains MSVC-specific flags which won't work with MinGW's gcc.

So if you use ActivePerl, you should stick with MSVC. If you want to use MinGW, switch to Strawberry Perl.

<strike>That said, `sys/types.h` is a POSIX header. If your module needs it, it probably doesn't support Windows regardless of the compiler you use. In that case, you can only switch to Cygwin which emulates a POSIX environment.</strike>

MSVC should come with `sys/types.h`. You probably didn't set it up correctly. Did you run `vcvars.bat`?

If you tell us which module you're trying to install, you might get a better answer.

Comment: the module i wanted is Moose. However i could install it using precompiled binaries using ppm. But Moose should definetly be supported on windows.

Comment: That's strange. Moose [doesn't include `sys/types.h`](https://github.com/moose/Moose/search?q=%23include&type=Code).

Comment: Did you set up MSVC by running `vcvars.bat`?